# apt-fast errors with installing qgis3?

Tags: ubuntu, qgis-3, apt-get

I am using `apt-fast` to install and upgrade QGIS-3 (2.99) under Ubuntu 16.04, which is a much faster method than the default `apt-get`. This works well until recently. I begin to get errors about `SSL/TLS handshake failure` (excerpts listed below). `apt-get upgrade` still works, but `apt-fast upgrade` consistently gives this error.

> 12/20 10:29:14 [ERROR] CUID#106 - Download aborted.
>   URI=http://qgis.org/ubuntugis-nightly/pool/main/q/qgis/libqgis-gui2.99.0_2.99.0+git20171219+70d61fd+24xenial-ubuntugis_amd64.deb
>   Exception: [AbstractCommand.cc:350] errorCode=1
>   URI=https://qgis.org/ubuntugis-nightly/pool/main/q/qgis/libqgis-gui2.99.0_2.99.0+git20171219+70d61fd+24xenial-ubuntugis_amd64.deb
>   -> [SocketCore.cc:975] errorCode=1 SSL/TLS handshake failure: Error in the pull function.
>
> ...
>
> 12/20 10:29:15 [NOTICE] Download GID#b992375f94b680b6 not complete:
>   /var/cache/apt/archives/apt-fast/qgis-common_1%3a2.99.0+git20171219+70d61fd+24xenial-ubuntugis_all.deb
>
> ...
>
> Download Results: gid   |stat|avg speed  |path/URI
>   ======+====+===========+======================================================= 5a2ca3|ERR |
>   17KiB/s|/var/cache/apt/archives/apt-fast/libqgis-core2.99.0_1%3a2.99.0+git20171219+70d61fd+24xenial-ubuntugis_amd64.deb
>   07ad77|ERR |
>   15KiB/s|/var/cache/apt/archives/apt-fast/libqgis-analysis2.99.0_1%3a2.99.0+git20171219+70d61fd+24xenial-ubuntugis_amd64.deb

Does anyone know how to fix the problem?

(I've tried `apt-get {autoremove|autoclean|clean}` to no avail.)

Comment: I've never used apt-fast - what is the benefit?

Comment: @DPSSpatial It's really `fast`, uses multiple threads to download, supports resume etc.

Comment: Hmmm... I'll have to try that!

Comment: I wonder why the error message has one `http` and one `https` URI.